# Condition for jumping efficiently

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile

**Question :** Grasshopper on the bottom of a cubical box has to jump out of the box each side.If each side of the box is $h=52~ \text{cm}$ and the grasshopper can jump with a maximum initial velocity $u=3~ \text{m/s}$ , what should be the minimum tilt angle $\theta$ the box be so that the grasshopper can jump out of the box. (Acceleration due to gravity is $g=10 ~\text{m/s}^2)$.
[image]

(That green dot is grasshopper)

**Attempt :** First we determine whether the grasshopper can jump through and escape the vessel when it is horizontal ($\theta = 0^{\circ}$).

Maximum height : $\dfrac{u^2}{2g}=\dfrac{3^2}{2 \times 10} = 0.45 \text{m} = 45 \text{cm} < 52 \text{cm}$

Clearly It cannot reach the maximum height even if it jumps vertically.Now let us tilt the vessel.

Now, I am not able to determine from where should the grasshopper jump most efficiently.

It cannot jump from the right-most point straight up because even if it covers sufficient height to escape ($h'=h \cos \theta$) it will land in the vessel itself. [image]

Also, as it goes up (through the base of vessel), it has to jump to lesser height, This seems favorable for grasshopper.But another problem is that max. height that can be reached is $\dfrac{u^2 \sin \alpha}{2g}$ which again decreases.Since, as we go up $\alpha$ will decrease $\implies$ $\sin \alpha$ decreases.,

Finally, my problem is that **is there any logical explanation or mathematical proof that from where should it jump?**

Hope I could explain my problem. (This is my first question on Physics SE,that +101 is association bonus.)

(If needed, The answer given is $30^{\circ}$)

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jaideep and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @JohnRennie Is my edit okay now, to get an answer?

Comment: Which year question is this (asking because I'm also preparing for JEE main and advanced)? Or from which book?

Comment: @WrichikBasu No this isn't any previous year question. This is from a book : Pathfinder for Olympiads and JEE Advanced Physics. http://www.amazon.in/Pathfinder-Olympiad-Tiwari-Singh-Jangid/dp/9332568715

Comment: Interesting though the problem is, it is an exercise so it falls under the homework and exercises policy. This requires that you **show your attempt** to solve the problem, and **ask about a conceptual difficulty**. You have not shown your attempt, neither have you identified a conceptual difficulty.

Comment: If your association rep is sufficient, you could try asking in the [JEE Preparation chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/jee-preparation). Alternatively, post on another site such as [Physics Q & A Exchange](http://physics.qandaexchange.com/?qa=questions) which was set up to deal with such questions.

Comment: Thank you for showing your attempt. The usual difficulty with such questions for this site is **asking about a conceptual difficulty**. It is not obvious whether or not *Is there any logical explanation or mathematical proof that from where should it jump?* is a conceptual difficulty. I shall give you the benefit of the doubt and vote to reopen the question. However, I think it is unlikely that the question will be reopened. I recommend that you try another option as I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: @sammygerbil This is surprising (to me) that Physics SE works different from Mathematics SE (There I have Rep - $2300$ at present) . There (Math SE), if someone has shown enough attempt from his side, his question is answered. I don't know how to elaborate my  'conceptual difficulty' more than this one. I hope this one gets reopened.BTW Thanks for voting to reopen. :)

Comment: I have posted an outline solution in the JEE Preparation chatroom.

Comment: @sammygerbil Thanks for help. Now I have got the way to proceed.

Comment: @JohnRennie Can you please vote to reopen this post?Please!! I have added my attempt more than 50 hrs ago, but there is no answer, neither the question is reopened. Is there any improvement that I should make? Should I delete this one and post it again as a fresh question?